# AES256 OpenSSL C++ and Java crypto : BadPaddingException while decrypting

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I am working on a program where a C++/Qt client communicates with a Java server. The client side uses OpenSSL library and server side uses Crypto library. The following are the functions used in both:

SERVER SIDE:

```
public static String encryptWithKey(String plaintext, String key) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecureRandom randomSecureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            byte[] iv = new byte[IVSIZE];
            randomSecureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key.getBytes("UTF-8")),"AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            
            byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            
            ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.write(iv);
            b.write(ciphertext);

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b.toByteArray());
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    public static String decryptWithKey(String ciphertext, String key) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            byte[] ciph = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext.getBytes());
            byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciph , 0, IVSIZE);
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(ciph,0,IVSIZE);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key.getBytes("UTF-8")),"AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciph);
            return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(plaintext, IVSIZE, plaintext.length));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

CLIENT SIDE:

```
int IVLENGTH = 16;
int KEYSIZE = 32;

QByteArray encryptAESWithExistingKey(QByteArray Base64AESKey, QByteArray &data){
    const char *temp_key=QByteArray::fromBase64(Base64AESKey).toStdString().c_str();
    //const char *temp_iv="Y)S$adw`=Tz2AFk";
    const char *temp_iv=randomBytes(IVLENGTH).data();
    unsigned char key[KEYSIZE];
    unsigned char iv[IVLENGTH];

    for(uint i=0;i<strlen(temp_key);i++){
        key[i]=temp_key[i];
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *en = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(en);

    if(!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(en, EVP_aes_256_cbc(),NULL,key, iv))
    {
        qCritical() << "EVP_EncryptInit_ex() failed " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        return QByteArray();
    }

    for(uint i=0;i<strlen(temp_iv);i++){
        iv[i]=temp_iv[i];
    }

    QByteArray str;
    for(int i=0;i<IVLENGTH;i++) {
        str.append(iv[i]);
    }

    char *input = data.data();
    int len = data.size();

    int c_len = len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE, f_len = 0;
    unsigned char *ciphertext = (unsigned char*)malloc(c_len);

    if(!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(en, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        qCritical() << "EVP_EncryptInit_ex() failed " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        return QByteArray();
    }


    if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(en, ciphertext, &c_len,(unsigned char *)input, len))
    {
        qCritical() << "EVP_EncryptUpdate() failed " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        return QByteArray();
    }

    if(!EVP_EncryptFinal(en, ciphertext+c_len, &f_len))
    {
        qCritical() << "EVP_EncryptFinal_ex() failed "  << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        return QByteArray();
    }

    len = c_len + f_len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cipher(en);

    QByteArray encrypted = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ciphertext), len);
    QByteArray finished;
    finished.append(str);
    finished.append(encrypted);

    free(ciphertext);

    return finished.toBase64();
}

QByteArray decryptAESWithExistingKey(QByteArray Base64AESKey, QByteArray &data){
    unsigned char key[KEYSIZE];
    unsigned char iv[IVLENGTH];
    
    data=QByteArray::fromBase64(data);
    QByteArray temp_iv=data.mid(0,IVLENGTH);
    data=data.mid(IVLENGTH);

    const char *temp_key=QByteArray::fromBase64(Base64AESKey).toStdString().c_str();

    for(uint i=0;i<strlen(temp_key);i++){
        key[i]=temp_key[i];
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *de = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(de);

    if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(de,EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
    {
        qCritical() << "EVP_DecryptInit_ex() failed" << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        return QByteArray();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<temp_iv.length();i++){
        iv[i]=temp_iv.at(i);
    }

    QByteArray str;
    for(int i=0;i<IVLENGTH;i++) {
        str.append(iv[i]);
    }

    char *input = data.data();
    int len = data.size();

    int p_len = len, f_len = 0;
    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc(p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(de, plaintext, &p_len, (unsigned char *)input, len))
    {
        qCritical() << "EVP_DecryptUpdate() failed " <<  ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        return QByteArray();
    }

    if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(de,plaintext+p_len,&f_len))
    {
        qCritical() << "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex() failed " <<  ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        return QByteArray();
    }

    len = p_len + f_len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(de);

    QByteArray decrypted = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(plaintext), len);
    free(plaintext);

    return decrypted;
}
```

I am pretty new to encryption coding and if the above codes look bad it is only my inexperience.

The problem is when I encrypt a string at the client side and send it across to the server for decryption, I get:

> BadPaddingException:Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

What am I doing wrong? I make the following function calls in my main functions in server and client side:

SERVER SIDE:

```
String key="YY3jic+tKY4O5+jLiJ/l2RHYORyIX8TeJ7TUy7Flbhg=";
String str="Hello server!"; //String as received from client
str=decryptWithKey(str,key);

if(str.equals("Hello server!")){
    String sendback=encryptWithKey("Hello client!",key);
    //Send encrypted string back to client
}
```

CLIENT SIDE:

```
QByteArray key="YY3jic+tKY4O5+jLiJ/l2RHYORyIX8TeJ7TUy7Flbhg=";
QByteArray message="Hello server!";
QByteArray enc=encryptAESWithExistingKey(key,message);

//Send to server and receive response
QByteArray response;
//Receive ciphertext from server and store it into "response"
qDebug()<<decryptAESWithExistingKey(key,response);
//Expected ouput: "Hello client"
```

The above code fails at decrypting in the server. Since BadPaddingException is thrown at server, it encrypts or returns nothing. Therefore, my client side disconnects after timeout.

I supply pre-generated AES256 key in Base64 format as function parameter. I tried using different AES256 keys generated with both OpenSSL and Java's crypto library. When a key is generated using one library, it is shared across a secure connection with the other side. Obciously, the same key is used in both sides for that particular runtime. I used the following code to generate the keys:

JAVA:

```
public byte[] generateNewAESKey(String password){
        byte[] key = "".getBytes();     
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(password.length()).getBytes(), 65536, 256);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
            key = secretKey.getEncoded();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginServiceThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Note: RandomStringUtils is from Apache Commons lang3 package.

OPENSSL C++:

```
int SALTSIZE = 8;
int KEYSIZE = 32;

QByteArray generateRandomAES(){
    QByteArray msalt = randomBytes(SALTSIZE);
    QByteArray passphrase = randomBytes(KEYSIZE);
    QByteArray returnkey;

    int rounds = 65536;
    unsigned char key[KEYSIZE];
    unsigned char iv[IVLENGTH] ;

    const unsigned char* salt = (const unsigned char*) msalt.constData();
    const unsigned char* password = (const unsigned char*) passphrase.constData();

    int i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha256(), salt, password, passphrase.length(),rounds,key,iv);


    for(int i=0;i<KEYSIZE;i++) {
        returnkey.append(key[i]);
    }

    return returnkey.toBase64();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does encryption and decryption not work smoothly between the two? Please help me with this one.

Comment: I suggest `toStdString().c_str();` is a fundamental problem The source of that key is a base64-encoded string already. Decoding that should result in the AES key *bytes* (which may contain zero or more null octets). Therefore, string operations are *not* appropriate once the base64 decode is done. In other words, most of the key management in that code therein is broken if indeed the input base64-encoded string is, in fact, the real AES key once decoded (and frankly, I can see no way it would not be). I also do not fathom a reason for the seemingly extra EVP_EncryptInit_ex call.

Comment: Hi WhozCraig. Thanks for the comment. Without the extra EVP_EncryptInit_ex call, Java side complains "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IV buffer too short for given offset/length combination".

I tried cutting out toStdString().c_str() and it doesn't seem to make any difference. I get the same BadPaddingException.

Comment: @BharathRam Those `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions leak memory on any errors.  In C++, use `std::vector<char>`, not `malloc`.  And yes, any C++ function that relies on null-terminated strings or uses the null-terminator to "stop", are not valid to use if the data may contain embedded nulls.  Please check all possibilities of this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you very much for this comment. I'll keep that in mind and make necessary changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important issue that I see is that you are using `iv` incorrectly. You need to provide `iv` to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` but you don't. You need to provide `iv` there and then send it to other side.

The problem is this part:

```
for(uint i=0;i<strlen(temp_key);i++){
    key[i]=temp_key[i];
}

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *en = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(en);

if(!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(en, EVP_aes_256_cbc(),NULL,key, iv))
{
    qCritical() << "EVP_EncryptInit_ex() failed " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
    return QByteArray();
}

for(uint i=0;i<strlen(temp_iv);i++){ // <<-- here is incorrect. need to be before EVP_EncryptInit_ex
    iv[i]=temp_iv[i];
}
```

There are other issues as mentioned in comments, but this is the main one. The same problem is in the decrypt function too.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for taking time and answering this, Afshin. This is a silly mistake and I didn't realize! Also I had made a few other mistakes like not cutting out the attached IV from the byte[] on the server side and so on.